# Unable to cast System.Double to System.Object. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda

Hello I am trying a cast a list of `Nullable<Double>` Properties to a `object[][]` property, as shown below.

```
WeibullLinearRegression.LinearRegressionPoints = await context.WeibullLinearRegressionPoints.Where(x => x.WeibullFilterDetailsId == filterId).Select(x => new object[] 
   { x.XCoordinate !=null? (double)x.XCoordinate : default(double), 
     x.YCoordinate != null ? (double)x.YCoordinate: default(double)
   }
).ToArrayAsync(token);
```

I tried all possible combinations, using default values etc still it throws me the error as below. Not sure why its happening.

```
Unable to cast System.Double to System.Object. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

*Update*

As some of the other posts suggested to try to use generic array, still didnt work! :(

```
WeibullLinearRegression.LinearRegressionPoints = await context.WeibullLinearRegressionPoints.Where(x => x.WeibullFilterDetailsId == filterId).Select(x => **new []** 
   { x.XCoordinate !=null? (double)x.XCoordinate : default(double), 
     x.YCoordinate != null ? (double)x.YCoordinate: default(double)
   }
).ToArrayAsync(token);
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need the database to perform the Select clause (because it can’t really which is why you are seeing an error)? If not, just put the Select after the ToArrayAsync, then another ToArray after that. Then the Select will be executed as native C# in memory rather than trying to be turned into some complex SQL query.

Comment: This was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above. The issue was query to the database was complex.

Solution - Convert to ToList and then shape the results.

Thanks @DaveM and @Flydog57

Following is the query which worked.

`(await context.WeibullLinearRegressionPoints.Where(x => x.WeibullFilterDetailsId == filterId).ToListAsync(token)).Select(x => new object[] { x.XCoordinate, x.YCoordinate }).ToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit lost on what you want to do particularly with the double dimensioned array.  And, I just did this with a list of objects, not with EF and all that.  So I created this type (sorry, shorter property names):

```
public class DataClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double? X { get; set; }
    public double? Y { get; set; }
    public DataClass (int id, double? x, double? y)
    {
        Id = id;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

Then I filled up a list of them:

```
var data = new List<DataClass>
{
    new DataClass(1, 1.0, 2.0),
    new DataClass(2, 2.0, 3.0),
    new DataClass(3, 3.0, null),
};
```

Then I did this query (using Linq syntax, not the extension methods):

```
 var result = from d in data
     where d.Id > 1
     select new[]
     {
         new
         {
             X = d.X ?? default(double),
             Y = d.Y ?? default(double)
         }
     };
 var array = result.ToArray();
```

The result is an double dimension array of anonymous types, but the array is [2][1].  In a watch window, it looks like (sorry for the formatting, but I can't figure out how to make it look better):

```
-       array   {<>f__AnonymousType0<double, double>[2][]}  <>f__AnonymousType0<double, double>[][]
-       [0] {<>f__AnonymousType0<double, double>[1]}    <>f__AnonymousType0<double, double>[]
+       [0] { X = 2, Y = 3 }    <Anonymous Type>
-       [1] {<>f__AnonymousType0<double, double>[1]}    <>f__AnonymousType0<double, double>[]
+       [0] { X = 3, Y = 0 }    <Anonymous Type>
```

Is that what you were trying to do?

OK, I stared at your original post a bit more and figured you wanted an array [N][2], where the two members were the X and Y elements.  So I tried this instead:

```
var result2 = from d in data
    where d.Id > 1
    select new[]
    {
        d.X ?? default(double),
        d.Y ?? default(double)
    };
var array2 = result2.ToArray();
```

And ended up with this in a watch window:

```
-       array2  {double[2][]}   double[][]
-       [0] {double[2]} double[]
    [0] 2   double
    [1] 3   double
-       [1] {double[2]} double[]
    [0] 3   double
    [1] 0   double
```

I think that might be closer. It *Should Just Work*(tm) with EF, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: It won’t “just work” with EF, that’s the real issue. Not everything that is expressable in C# can be turned into valid SQL and that is the issue here.

Comment: Hence the italicized "Should Just Work". At that point, you need to play some games - games that cost memory.  Pull the collection in from the DB (with ToList, or whatever) and then in a second pass, shape into what you want.  You might be able to do get part of the work done EF-style, and then finish it up with a foreach.  Sorry - I tried.  Does getting a List<double[]> work with EF (using ToList rather than ToArray)?

Comment: Thank you DaveM and Flydog57.

The real issue as pointed out by both of you was that SQL query was too complex because of the Select query on the database. 

Converting toListAsync and then Selecting on it worked perfectly!

Lesson Learnt - _Keep queries to DB simple, and then shape the results using Linq later!_

Thanks Guys.

Comment: This is the query which worked!

`(await context.WeibullLinearRegressionPoints.Where(x => x.WeibullFilterDetailsId == filterId).ToListAsync(token)).Select(x => new object[] { x.XCoordinate, x.YCoordinate }).ToArray()`